# What can be said about the continuous function $f:\mathbb R^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that has only finitely many $0$'s $?$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

$f\colon \mathbb R^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb R$  is  a  continuous  map that  assumes  $0$  for  only  finitely  many  points. Then  which  one  is  true

A. either $f(x)\le 0$ for  all  $x$ or $f(x)\ge 0$  for  all  $x$.

B. $f$  is  onto

C.  $f$  is  one-one

D. none  of  the  above

Actually  not  many  useful  thoughts. $\mathbb R^{2}$  to $\mathbb R$  onto  continuous  map  does  exist. If "finitely  many"  can  be  more  than  $1$  it  won't  be  one-one. A.  means  it  is  bounded  above  or  below  by $0$. But  why  does  it  have  to  be  bounded?

Comment: What are you thoughts?

Comment: The formulation of A may be considered ambiguous. At least the interpretation  $\forall x\in\mathbb R^2\,(f(x)\le 0\lor f(x)\ge 0)$ is true even ifwe ignore continuity.

Comment: Try to find a continuous function that disproves each of them, one at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interpreting A as 
$$\left( \forall x\in\mathbb R^2\colon f(x)\ge 0\right)\lor \left( \forall x\in\mathbb R^2\colon f(x)\le 0\right)$$
we can show that it is true. Assume otherwise. Then there exist points $x_1,x_2$ with $f(x_1)<0<f(x_2)$. Now for any continuous curve $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to \mathbb R^2$ with $\gamma(0)=x_1$, $\gamma(1)=x_2$ we see from the IVT applied to $f\circ\gamma$ that $f(\gamma(t))=0$ for some $t\in(0,1)$. We can easily pick $\gamma$ so that it avoids the finite set of zeroes (actually, we could just as easily avoid a countable set of zeroes), we obtain a contradiction.

Comment: Like  if  I  take  $\gamma $  such  that  it  takes $[0,\delta )$  for  $\delta \lt 1$  to $x_{0}$  and  $[\delta , 1]$  covers  the  rest  from $x_{0}$  to  $x_{1}$  then will  that  work?

Comment: @user118494 No, that's not continouous. Draw a line through $x_1$ that avoids the zeroes, draw a line through $x_2$ that avoids the zeroes and is not parallel to the previous line. Then you can continuously walk along these lines (via the intersection point) from $x_1$ to $x_2$

Comment: +1 So a function from $\mathbb R^2$ with finitely many zeros has constant sign. That's radically different from the $\mathbb R$ case! Very nice :-)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : Thanks  for  the  answer .  But  how  do  I  confirm  that  the  other  options  are  not  correct  at  all , like  with  counter  examples  or  contradictions  ? I  could  use  a  little  more  help.

Comment: @user118494 take $f = 1$; clearly is not onto. for C, take any periodic function with no zeros. like $f(x,y) = 2 + \sin(x + y)$; is not one-one